# Call other Tcl commands from a custom command (Tcl_CmdProc)

Tags: c, tcl

At first glance (see the evidence below), it looks like while a [`Tcl_CmdProc`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/CrtCommand.htm) has control, the interpreter is waiting for it to return and can't accept any other calls in the meantime.

So, **how do I make any calls into Tcl before returning** like e.g. a user-defined function would do? I guess I may need to set up a new call stack frame in the interpreter or something (and unwind it later). [`Tcl_CreateCommand` man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/CrtCommand.htm) says nothing on this matter.

The big picture is like this:

I'm fixing https://bugs.python.org/issue33257 . The [TkinterHandlers.py](https://bugs.python.org/file47536/TkinterHanders.py) example uses Python event handlers that are implemented as custom Tcl commands under the hood. Currently, their implementation releases the "Tcl lock" (a Python-specific lock that it wraps all Tcl calls with) while executing Python code and reacquires it to `Tcl_SetObjResult` at the end -- thus allowing other calls to the same interpreter in the meantime.

Now, if another call into the interpreter is actually made during this time frame, Tcl `abort`s shortly with a message on `stderr`: `TclStackFree: incorrect freePtr. Call out of sequence?`

And if I make the custom command hold on to the Tcl lock, it later freezes trying to acquire the lock again because it itself also needs to make a Tcl call sometimes. Now, I can make the lock reentrant, but without knowing how to handle the interpreter right, I'll probably break it, too.

---

**To keep this question on topic, I'm specifically asking about how to handle the interpreter, and make Tcl calls in particular, from a `Tcl_CmdProc`.** The specific situation is solely for exposition to illustrate my needs. If this is actually explained in some doc that I couldn't find, linking to it and reciting some key points would be sufficient.

Comment: I suggest you show code or point to it. This will help clarify what you mean by "thus allowing other calls to the same interpreter in the meantime." The Tcl threading model maintains one interpreter per (user-space) thread. If you have interleaving `Tcl_CmdProc` executions hammering onto one and the same interp, there is something fundamentally wrong. Event handlers as commands map to Tcl events managed by the Tcl event loop. Better watch out for [`Tcl_DoWhenIdle`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/DoWhenIdle.htm), [`Tcl_QueueEvent`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Notifier.htm)

Comment: @mrcalvin the C code is [Python's `_tkinter` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_tkinter.c) that runs as a part of a Python installation. The custom command implementation there is `Tkapp_PythonCmd`, regular Tcl calls from Python are made via `Tkapp_Call`, and the event loop is `_tkinter_tkapp_mainloop_impl`. The linked `.py` file is Python code that demonstrates the aforementioned crash.

Comment: _DO NOT_ call a Tcl interpreter from any OS thread other than the one it was created in; Tcl's implementation uses thread-local storage quite extensively to avoid global locks, but it means that multithreaded usage will definitely blow up every time.

Comment: Those are also not the only place where the single-threaded-ness of an interpreter is assumed; it sounds like you hit problems in one of our high-performance memory allocators. That's an absolute “what you are doing is unsupported; stop doing it” failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a Tcl command from C code, you've got a choice between two API function families. One is `Tcl_EvalObjv`, and the other is `Tcl_Eval`. Each has a number of variants, but the only variant I'll mention is `Tcl_EvalObjEx`.

### `Tcl_EvalObjv`

This function invokes a single Tcl command, with *no* processing of substitutions in arguments (unless the command itself does them, of course). It has this signature:

```
int Tcl_EvalObjv(Tcl_Interp *interp,
                 int objc,
                 Tcl_Obj *const objv[],
                 int flags);
```

It takes the description of what command to call and what arguments to pass to it as a C array of Tcl value references (in argument `objv`) where the array is of length `objc`; Tcl guarantees to not modify the array itself, but might transform the values if it does type conversions. The values *must* all have a non-zero reference count (and all values start with a zero reference count from their birthing `Tcl_NewObj` call). The `interp` is the interpreter context, and `flags` can usually be zero.

The result is a Tcl exception code; if it is `TCL_OK`, the result of the call can be retrieved from the interpreter using `Tcl_GetObjResult`, and if the exception code is `TCL_ERROR` then there was an error and you should usually pass that on out (perhaps adding to the stack trace with `Tcl_AddErrorInfo`). Other exception codes are possible; it's usually best to just pass those straight on out without doing any further processing (unless you're making something loop-like, when you should pay attention to `TCL_BREAK` and `TCL_CONTINUE`).

### `Tcl_Eval`

This function evaluates a Tcl script, not just a single command, and that includes processing substitutions in arguments. It has this signature:

```
int Tcl_Eval(Tcl_Interp *interp,
             const char *script);
```

The `script` is any old C string; Tcl won't modify it, but it will parse, bytecode-compile, and execute it. *It's up to you* to provide the script in a form that will execute a single command without surprises. The `interp` argument and the result of the function call are the same as for `Tcl_EvalObjv`.

If you're interested in using this for running a single command, you're actually better off using `Tcl_EvalObjv` or…

### `Tcl_EvalObjEx`.

This is like `Tcl_Eval` except it takes the script as a Tcl value reference (and takes `flags` too).

```
int Tcl_EvalObjEx(Tcl_Interp *interp,
                  Tcl_Obj *objPtr,
                  int flags);
```

Again, make sure the `objPtr` has a non-zero reference count before passing it into this function. (It may adjust the reference count during execution.) Again, `interp` and the result are as documented for `Tcl_EvalObjv`, and `flags` is too.

The advantage of this for calling single commands is that you can call `Tcl_NewListObj` (or any other list-building function) to make the script value; doing so ***guarantees*** that there will be no surprise substitutions. But you could also go directly to invoking the command with `Tcl_EvalObjv`. But if you want to process anything more complex than a single simple call to a command, this is a good place to start as it has a key advantage that plain `Tcl_Eval` doesn't: it can make the type of the script passed in via `objPtr` be one that caches the compiled bytecode, allowing quite a reasonable performance gain in some circumstances.

Note that `Tcl_EvalObjv` is effectively the API that Tcl calls internally to invoke *all* user code and perform *all* I/O. (“Effectively” because things get more complex in Tcl 8.6.)

---

**Within a `Tcl_CmdProc`, all these functions can be called as usual, no special processing or "handling of the interpreter" is needed.** If this doesn't work for you, causing crashes or whatever, the interpreter is not at fault, something else must be wrong with your code.

Comment: Okay, but how do these calls work while a `Tcl_CmdProc` has control? Can I just call them from that proc at any time, without any special processing?

Comment: The `Tcl_CmdProc` can call them as much as it wants. _Other threads must not._ Tcl's assumed thread model keeps each interpreter within a single thread, and yes, this is very different to that of Python.